# sumar números de una columna y mostrar en otra columna el total y en otro el porcentaje SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

actualmente tengo este query

```
SELECT
t2.Concepto,
t2.Monto
FROM Transacciones2 t2
```

que me arroja este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que quiero es sumar la columna MONTO y me lo muestre en otra columna, y en base a ello también una columna con el porcentaje

Este es el resultado que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo TOTAL seria la suma de toda la columna de MONTO, y el porcentaje dividiendo el Monto/Total, si alguien me ayuda ya que no se como plasmarlo en el query

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
t2.Concepto,
t2.Monto,
sum(t2.Monto) as Total,
(monto/sum(t2.Monto)) * 100 as Porcentaje
from Transacciones2 t2
```

Cuando haces la **clausula select** para proyectar los datos incorporas dos campos mas, uno que sea el **monto total** utilizando la **función de agregación Sum**, y otro que sea el porciento que representa cada monto del monto total.

Si deseas redondear (truncar) el porcentaje a dos decimales para que no te salgan tantos valores después de la coma puedes usar la **función Round**, entonces la parte donde calculas el porcentaje podría quedarte de esta forma:

```
Round((monto/sum(t2.Monto)) * 100, 2, 1)
```

Esta función recibe tres parámetros, el calculo del porcentaje (que es un numero), los decimales a mostrar después de la coma y un tercer parámetro opcional que si es **0** indica que el primer parámetro será redondeado, de no ser cero indica que será truncado.

En el ejemplo que te pongo truncamos el valor a dos decimales.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener la sumatoria en una columna adicional puedes utilizar la cláusula `over` de la siguiente manera:

```
select
t2.Concepto,
t2.Monto,
sum(Monto) over (  ) as total, 
Monto/ sum(Monto) over (  ) as porcentaje
from Transacciones2 t2
```